# Error: Call to a member function addWhere() on array in hook_views_query_alter()

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I'm getting the error 'Call to a member function addWhere() on array' in my hook. 
Any thoughts? 
I just need to add WHERE clause to my query.

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;

/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_query_alter
 *
 * @param $view
 * @param $query
 */   
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  if ($view->id() == 'search_filter' && $view->getDisplay()->display['id'] == 'block_1') {
    $field = 'node__field_country.field_country_target_id';
    $value = 'somevalue';
    $operator = '=';
    $query->addWhere(0, $field, $value, $operator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add your condition to conditions array in the where  `$query->where` like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function myModule_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  if ($view->id() === 'search_filter' && $view->current_display === 'block_1') {
    $field = 'node__field_country.field_country_target_id';
    $value = 'someValue';
    $operator = '=';
    if (isset($query->where[1]['conditions'])) {
      $query->where[1]['conditions'][] = [
        "field"    => $field,
        "value"    => $value,
        "operator" => $operator,
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

Read this [Article](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/using-hook-views-query-alter) it's very useful.

Comment: Thank for this, at least I see how to modify 'where' queries. But why I get an error with addWhere method, I just take this examples from here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.2.x

Answer (score 0):

Try This code, In drupal 8 we cannot use 'function myModule_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
'. Refer Below code, This works for me, Above code not worked for me. Hope this will helpfull.

```
function Hook_views_query_alter($view, $query) {
   if ($view->id() == 'content') {    
      $field = 'node_field_data.langcode';
      $value = array('en');
      $operator = 'IN';
      $query->where[1]['conditions'][] = [
        "field"    => $field,
        "value"    => $value,
        "operator" => $operator,
      ];
  }
}
```